# How do I make my flipping image display a different image on either side with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the different sides of the object display different images; however, any similar question I've seen has an incredibly overcomplicated answer. I'm not too fluent in js just yet but I'd appreciate the help.

```
<script>
  var k = 0;

  function flip() {
    var j = document.getElementById("card");
    k += 720;
    j.style.transform = "rotatey(" + k + "deg)";
    j.style.transitionDuration = "7s"
    }

</script>
<div id="card" onmouseover="flip()"><img src="day.png"></div>
```

That is my html and here is my CSS:

```
#card {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

Let me know if any clarification is needed, thanks for the help!

Edit: I currently have an object that rotates along the y-axis when moused over. I would like there to be another image displayed after the initial image has rotated 90 degrees (displaying from 90-270 degrees, and then switching back to the previous image from 270-450 degrees, and so on). Not sure why the post was downvoted, but I hope this is the ludicrous specificity they were looking for.

Comment: `any similar question I've seen has an incredibly overcomplicated answer` Because what you're trying to do **is** complicated, from what I understand. You want to flip it like how you would in real life, with a 3D plane and such, correct?

Comment: You'll have to forgive my ignorance, The functionality seems straightforward and works as is. Essentially, I want it to have a heads and a tails side, that is all.

Comment: How does this jQuery library do? https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do this with CSS and HTML alone.

```css
.card-container {
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.card-container:hover .card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card-container, .front, .back {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.front, .back {
  background: #efe;
}
.card {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}
.front, .back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      Front
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      Back
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to type this out. The problem is I don't want it to flip back to the front after mousing off of the object. Is there a way to do that with CSS and HTML alone?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Javascript too and I don't know if this is the best solution to use in a production environment but here's what I came up with.

Basically, you can rotate the image 180 degrees and change the image source attribute halfway. So, if you set your rotation to complete in 1 second, you can use `setTimeout` with a delay of around half a second to call a function that will change the image source.

```js
var k = 0;

var imgSrc1 = "https://static.pexels.com/photos/9291/nature-bird-flying-red.jpg";
var imgSrc2 = "http://media-channel.nationalgeographic.com/media/uploads/photos/content/video/2014/10/29/349582915975_349582915975_720p_5994_Racing_Speeds_DMS.jpg";

var img = document.getElementById("img");

img.onmouseover = flip;
img.style.transitionDuration = "1s";

function flip() {
    k += 180;
    img.style.transform = "rotatey(" + k + "deg)";
    setTimeout(changeImgSrc(), 300);
}
function changeImgSrc() {
 return function() {
       if(img.getAttribute("src") === imgSrc1)
   img.src = imgSrc2;
       else
         img.src = imgSrc1;
    }
}
```

```css
img { width:150px; height: 150px;}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/9291/nature-bird-flying-red.jpg">
```

Comment: At first glance, this works great. I pulled the code out and put it in my local file but as soon as I put in local images it just breaks and only displays one rotating image. not sure why this is.

Comment: @Digglit What kind of development environment do you have setup?

Comment: @Digglit It's most likely a path issue. If you're referencing your local images with a relative path, this will happen because `img.src` returns the absolute path. I updated my answer to use `if(img.getAttribute("src") === imgSrc1)` instead of `if(img.src === imgSrc1)` in `function changeImgSrc()`. Hope that helps.